# TileMill looses fonts and color boxes in legend while uploading to MapBox. How can I fix this?

Tags: legend, mapbox, tilemill

So it is: Colorboxes and fonts disapear from legend after uploading to Mapbox. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem and it turns out it came down to TileMill (or at least the way I'm running it on OS X Mavericks) replacing ' with ’

Make sure that all single quotes are the former (') not the latter (’) and it should take care of your problem!